# The function $f(x)=|x|$ has a derivative at $x=0$?

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

The function $f(x)=|x|$ has a derivative at $x=0$?

I already know about $|x|$ is not differentiable at zero.
But I can't solve if $|x|$ has a derivative at $x=0$.
When $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$, a derivative is $1$, and $\lim_{h \to 0^-}$, a derivative is $-1$.

How about at $x=0$? Help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.

Comment: No, it is a corner and not differentiable.

Comment: What is wrong with the conclusion that the derivative does not exist at zero?

Comment: If the two limits (left and right) do not coincide we say that the limit does not exist at that point. In this case, as the limit is the derivative, we say that the derivative does not exist (or the function is not differentiable) at that point.

Comment: "$|x|$ is differentiable at $0$" and "$|x|$ has a derivative at $0$" mean exactly the same thing.  The derivative does not exist, for the very reason you gave.  I can't figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows that you actually know all the correct things about the absolute value function in order to answer for yourself. It does have left and right derivatives at $0$. In order for the function to be differentiable there these would have to be equal, and they're not.

Comment: Thank you for your explain.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not defined at $x=0$, since the one side limit exist but are different the limit at $x=0$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot...!